# Fisheye lens calibration

Tags: projection

I am writing a lens correctionion code and the process should do several things:

- Inverse fisheye projection to obtain rectilinear image
- Barrel/pincushion correction
- Vignetting correction
- Lateral chromatic aberration correction

The problem is - in what order apply these steps?

Should the image be first "de-fished" or the chromatic aberration, vignetting etc. affects already formed fisheye image?

I am not familiar with optics so maybe any ordering is okay as long as correct models/parameters are used - but I would like to go for simplest solution in that case - e.g. if chromatic aberration is most easily corrected in rectilinear images, then de-fishing should go first.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I found an answer on the [Panotools Wiki](http://wiki.panotools.org/Lens_correction_model):

> Unlike rectilinear lenses, fish-eye lenses do not follow the
>   tangent-plane geometry, but instead have built-in distortions designed
>   to achieve wide fields of view. The radial lens distortion parameters
>   are used the same way for rectilinear lenses and fisheye lenses, but
>   they should never be used to attempt to remap a fisheye to a
>   rectilinear image. This is done by selecting the proper source and
>   destination projection. Fisheye geometry follows a rapidly-changing
>   trigonometric function which can hardly be approximated by a third
>   degree polynomial.
>
> For fisheyes, the lens correction parameters correct for the deviation
>   between a real lens and the ideal fisheye geometry.

The last sentence suggests that the lens correction is done to get a proper geometry of whatever lens it is. The fisheye is therefore remapped *after* the lens corrections are done.

Looking at the [Fulla](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/Fulla.html) tool source code from Hugin, it seems that it performs corrections in the following order:

1. Flat-field correction (i.e. removing vignetting
2. Radial distortion correction (barrel, pincushion, wavy distortion)
3. TCA correction (i.e. removing one type of chromatic aberration)